# Element type is invalid REACT..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to REACT and I've been getting the following warning:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import App from "./App";
   6 | //import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
   7 | 
>  8 | ReactDOM.render(
   9 |   <BrowserRouter>
  10 |     <App />
  11 |   </BrowserRouter>,



My classes are: (index.js)
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";
//import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

//serviceWorker.unregister();
```

(App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import AddPatient from "./components/add-patient.component";
import Patient from "./components/patient.component";
import PatientsList from "./components/patient-list.component";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <a href="/doctor/patients" className="navbar-brand">
            ReactApp
          </a>
          <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to={"/doctor/patients"} className="nav-link">
                Patients
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to={"/doctor/newpatient"} className="nav-link">
                Add Patient
              </Link>
            </li>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div className="container mt-3">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/doctor/patients"]} component={PatientsList} />
            <Route exact path="/doctor/newpatient" component={AddPatient} />
            <Route path="/doctor/patient/:id" component={Patient} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Been trying to understand this error but so far no clue, even after trying multiple things suggested on the internet.

Comment: There might be an issue with other imported files.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: After further inspection, it seems you are simply exporting your App component incorrectly.

Change: `class App extends Component {` in your App.js

To this: `class App extends React.Component {`

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Since there is `import React, { Component } ...` it is okay this way.